# mysql - How to pass main query value into a join in subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, visibility

I have the following query (well... the part that bugs me of it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `serv`.`id`, `serv`.`name`, `prj`.`id` AS `idProject`, `prj`.`name` AS `projectName`, `units`.`id` AS `idUnit`,
    `units`.`name` AS `unitName`, `units`.`description` AS `unitDescription`, `units`.`descriptionLong` AS `unitLongDescription`,
    `units`.`address`, `units`.`telephone`, (
        SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`subserv`.`id`, '|', `subserv`.`name`, '|', `links`.`continuous`))
        FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "` AS `subserv`
        JOIN `" . DBT_SERV_LINKS . "` AS `links` ON (
            `links`.`deleted` = 0 AND
            `links`.`idProject` = `serv`.`idProject` AND
            `links`.`mandatory` = '1' AND
            `links`.`subserviceLink` = 1 AND
            `links`.`serviceFrom` LIKE CONCAT ('|', `serv`.`id`,'|') AND
            `links`.`serviceTo` LIKE CONCAT('|', `subserv`.`id`, '|')
        )
        WHERE `idParentService` = `serv`.`id`
            AND `subserv`.`deleted` = 0
            AND `subserv`.`onSaleStatus` = 'onSale'
            AND `subserv`.`serviceGroup` = 'SS'
    ) AS `subservices`, (
        SELECT `file`
        FROM `" . DBT_GALLERY . "` AS `gallery`
        WHERE `gallery`.`category` = 'accommodationUnit'
            AND `idObject` = `idUnit`
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `picture`
FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "` AS `serv`
```

ETC., ETC... some more joins and a where.

My problem is that I get the following error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'serv.idProject' in 'on clause'

If I remove  `links`.`idProject` = `serv`.`idProject` AND I get #1054 - Unknown column 'serv.id=' in 'on clause'.

Basically... I can't see anything from `serv` inside the ON clause. If I remove whole JOIN query works, so in the WHERE clause `serv` is visible. Any idea how I can make it work in the ON clause also?

Comment: Could you insert here result command SHOW CREATE tbl_name for all tables you use in query?

Comment: I'm in hospital for 2 days (don't have access from here)... after this, I'll be glad.

Comment: you write in the first line:  `prj`.`id` AS `idProject` so `idProject` is from the table `prj` and not from `serv`, or did i miss something?...could you provide [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/) an example

Comment: You are doing a regular inner `JOIN`, did you try putting those conditions in the `WHERE` clause instead of in the `ON` ?

Comment: @Igoel idProject is an alias for project id (column id in table projects), and a column in service table. Probably not the best choice for an alias, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: yes and what i also mean in the line:
`links`.`idProject` = `serv`.`idProject`
 the column doens´t exists in your table serv, so you you shouldnt point to it,.....point to `prj`.`idProject`

Comment: @Igoel it exists in both tables, and as a coincidence has the same value. The problem still persist, even if used prj.idProject. Is same case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT `serv`.`SID`, `serv`.`SNAME`, `serv`.`SIDP`, `prj`.`id` AS `idProject`,
`prj`.`name` AS `projectName`, `units`.`id` AS `idUnit`,
`units`.`name` AS `unitName`, `units`.`description` AS `unitDescription`,
`units`.`descriptionLong` AS `unitLongDescription`, `units`.`address`, 
`units`.`telephone`,
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`subserv`.`id`, '|', `subserv`.`name`, '|', `links`.`continuous`))
        FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "` AS `subserv`
        JOIN `" . DBT_SERV_LINKS . "` AS `links` ON (
            `links`.`deleted` = 0 AND
            `links`.`idProject` = `serv`.`SIDP` AND
            `links`.`mandatory` = '1' AND
            `links`.`subserviceLink` = 1 AND
            `links`.`serviceFrom` LIKE CONCAT ('|', `serv`.`SID`,'|') AND
            `links`.`serviceTo` LIKE CONCAT('|', `subserv`.`id`, '|')
        )
        WHERE `idParentService` = `serv`.`SID`
            AND `subserv`.`deleted` = 0
            AND `subserv`.`onSaleStatus` = 'onSale'
            AND `subserv`.`serviceGroup` = 'SS'
    ) AS `subservices`, (
        SELECT `file`
        FROM `" . DBT_GALLERY . "` AS `gallery`
        WHERE `gallery`.`category` = 'accommodationUnit'
            AND `idObject` = `idUnit`
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `picture`
FROM 
    (SELECT `id` AS `SID`, `idProject` AS `SIDP`, `name` AS `SNAME` FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "`) AS serv
ETC., ETC... some more joins and a where.
```

SID, SNAME and SIDP alias are defined in the principal query so it should be accesible into subquerys.

Answer (score 3):

In the inner select, you are only joining `subserv` and `links`, hence you cannot use other tables in `ON`. You should be able to access the outer table in a `WHERE` clause, however:

```
... (
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`subserv`.`id`, '|', `subserv`.`name`, '|', `links`.`continuous`))
                FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "` AS `subserv`
                JOIN `" . DBT_SERV_LINKS . "` AS `links` ON (
                    `links`.`deleted` = 0 AND
                    `links`.`mandatory` = '1' AND
                    `links`.`subserviceLink` = 1 AND
                    `links`.`serviceTo` LIKE CONCAT('|', `subserv`.`id`, '|')
                WHERE `links`.`idProject` = `serv`.`idProject` AND
                      `links`.`serviceFrom` LIKE CONCAT ('|', `serv`.`id`,'|') 
                )
...
```

should work for the inner subselect.

Comment: True, but I was looking for a more general answer (still... +1)

Comment: @zozo In which sense did you mean "more general"? A `JOIN` is a local operation with a local `ON` clause, which only can access the tables mentioned in the `JOIN`. And to access tables outside from the subselect, you have to use `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

> The alias(serv) doesn't exist during the subquery compilation
>   since the outer query cannot be compiled until the subquery is
>   considered valid and its output known.

So the quick solution is just **replace serv with DBT_SERV in your subquery.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `serv`.`id`, `serv`.`name`, `prj`.`id` AS `idProject`, `prj`.`name` AS `projectName`, `units`.`id` AS `idUnit`,
    `units`.`name` AS `unitName`, `units`.`description` AS `unitDescription`, `units`.`descriptionLong` AS `unitLongDescription`,
    `units`.`address`, `units`.`telephone`, (
        SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`subserv`.`id`, '|', `subserv`.`name`, '|', `links`.`continuous`))
        FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "` AS `subserv`
        JOIN `" . DBT_SERV_LINKS . "` AS `links` ON (
            `links`.`deleted` = 0 AND
            `links`.`idProject` = `" . DBT_SERV . "`.`idProject` AND
            `links`.`mandatory` = '1' AND
            `links`.`subserviceLink` = 1 AND
            `links`.`serviceFrom` LIKE CONCAT ('|', `" . DBT_SERV . "`.`id`,'|') AND
            `links`.`serviceTo` LIKE CONCAT('|', `subserv`.`id`, '|')
        )
        WHERE `idParentService` = `" . DBT_SERV . "`.`id`
            AND `subserv`.`deleted` = 0
            AND `subserv`.`onSaleStatus` = 'onSale'
            AND `subserv`.`serviceGroup` = 'SS'
    ) AS `subservices`, (
        SELECT `file`
        FROM `" . DBT_GALLERY . "` AS `gallery`
        WHERE `gallery`.`category` = 'accommodationUnit'
            AND `idObject` = `idUnit`
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `picture`
FROM `" . DBT_SERV . "` AS `serv`
```